# When do blowups ''commute''?

Tags: blow-ups, reference-request, manifolds, dg.differential-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $M$ be a manifold (variety, scheme, your favorite object) and let $N_1,N_2$ be two submanifolds (subvarieties, closed subschemes, ideal sheafes, etc.) such that $N_1 \cap N_2 \neq \emptyset$. Denote by $\text{BL}_{N_i}M$ the blowup of $M$ along $N_i, i=1,2$ and let $\text{BL}_{N_1}\text{BL}_{N_2}M$ be the blowup of $\text{BL}_{N_1}M$  along the proper transform $N_2^\prime$ of $N_2$. (Define $\text{BL}_{N_2}\text{BL}_{N_1}M$ vice versa).

> Question: Under which conditions does the following hold: $\text{BL}_{N_1}\text{BL}_{N_2}M \cong \text{BL}_{N_2}\text{BL}_{N_2}M$ ?

This should be true if we are in the situation $N_1 \subseteq N_2 \subseteq M$, since ``blowups commute with restriction'' but is it in genreal true? If so, is there some reference available? If not, is there a criterium when blow ups commute (e.g. something like transversal intersection or) or/and can you come up with an easy counterexample?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sándor is exactly right, this generally isn't true.  However, there is a related statement that is always true, instead of blowing up strict transforms of $N_1$ and $N_2$, you should blow up total transforms.

---

### Blowing up total transforms

Suppose that $I_1$ and $I_2$ are the ideals defining $N_1$ and $N_2$ in $M$.  Let $$Y_1 = Bl_{I_1} M = Bl_{N_1} M.$$
Now define the *total transform of* $I_2$, denoted $\overline{I_{2}}$, to be the ideal formed by extending $I_2$ to $Y_1$, in other words $\overline{I_2} = I_2 \cdot O_{Y_1}$ (note that by the universal property of blowing up $I_1 \cdot O_{Y_1}$ is an invertible sheaf).

$\overline{I_2}$ need not define a manifold, or even a reduced scheme, but we can still blow it up.  Set $$Y_{1,2} = Bl_{\overline{I_2}} Y_1.$$
I claim:

**Theorem:** *We have* $Y_{1,2} = Y_{2,1}$ *where the second object is obtained in the same way but blowing up* $I_2$ *first.*

There are at least two ways to see this.

1. You can do this from the universal property of blowing up.
2. Since you already assumed that $M$ is a manifold, it is integral.  Thus the charts of a blowup can be computed as follows.  Suppose $M = \text{Spec } A$ is affine for simplicity.  If $\langle x_1, \dots, x_n\rangle$ generate an ideal $I$, then as $i = 1,...,n$ varies, $Y_{I,i} = \text{Spec } A[x_1/x_i, \dots, x_i/x_i, \dots, x_n/x_i]$ are affine charts covering the blowup.  $Y_I = Bl_I Y$.

**EDIT:** As Dustin Cartwright points out in a comment below, blowing up $I_1$ followed by blowing up $\overline{I_2}$ is the same as blowing up $I_1 \cdot I_2$.

---

### A normal crossings example

I'd like to give you an example in $\mathbb{A}^4 = \text{Spec } k[x,y,u,v]$ showing the difference between blowing up strict transforms and total transforms, even when the $N_i$ intersect transversally (are in normal crossings).  Let $N_1 = V(x,y)$ be a plane and let $N_2 = V(y,u,v)$ be a line.

Suppose we blowup the line $N_2$ first, then the strict transform and the total transform of $N_1$ coincide.  In particular, $Y_{2,1}$ is the object you were considering.

On the other hand, let's blow up $N_1$ first, in this case the strict transform $\widetilde{N_2}$ of $N_2$ is a line, but the total transform $\overline{N_2}$ of $N_2$ is two lines.  $\overline{N_2}$ contains the strict transform but also one of the new $\mathbb{P}^1$'s lying over the origin of $N_1 \subseteq \mathbb{A}^4$.  The blowups of the strict and total transform of $N_2$ on $Y_1$ are thus manifestly different.

One can check that $Y_{1,2} = Y_{2,1}$ if you did the total transform blowup, and so blowing up the strict transforms does not commute.

**Note:** If I recall correctly, you can also do the example when two planes are *kissing.*  $N_1 = V(x,y)$, $N_2 = V(u,v)$.  The same sort of thing happens, but it's even messier.  I've seen this example in various papers on resolution of singularities.

---

### In the literature

The difference between strict and total transforms plays a key role in modern resolution of singularities algorithms.  Even though conceptually strict transforms are much easier to think about, they are much *harder* to compute or control.  Thus modern algorithms tend to use total transforms instead in *SOME* places, and then peel off any copies of the exceptional you can, while possibly leaving embedded components.

See for example:

1. Section 7 of [This paper by Bravo-Encinas-Villamayor](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206244v2.pdf)
2. Example 2.3 of [This paper by Howard Thompson](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.1915.pdf)

Comment: Nice answer!!!!

Comment: I wanted to add that the iterated blow-ups of the weak transforms $Y_{1,2} = Y_{2,1}$ are also isomorphic to the blow-up of the product ideal $I_1 I_2$. This is another way to see that the order of the blow-ups doesn't matter.

Comment: That's a great point, I'll add it to the answer as well.  Thanks.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much!

Comment: Dear Professor Cartwright, how to show that $Y_{1,2}=Y_{2,1}$ are also isomorphic to the blow-up of the product ideal $I_1I_2$?

Answer (score 7):

This generally fails even under nice circumstances.

Let $M$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb C$ of (say) dimension $3$ such that it does not contain a rational curve. For instance an abelian threefold. Let $N_1$ and $N_2$ be two smooth projective curves in $M$ intersecting in (at least) a point and for simplicity assume that the intersection is transversal in exactly one point. Finally, let $B=BL_{N_1}BL_{N_2}M$ and $B'=BL_{N_2}BL_{N_1}M$.

The preimage of $N_1$ in $B$, $E_1$ is a $\mathbb P^1$-bundle (ruled surface) over $N_1$ and the preimage of $N_2$, $E_2$ is a $\mathbb P^1$-bundle over $N_2$ blown-up at a point. Similarly the preimage of $N_2$ in $B'$, $E_2'$ is a $\mathbb P^1$-bundle  over $N_2$ and the preimage of $N_1$, $E_1'$ is a $\mathbb P^1$-bundle over $N_1$ blown-up at a point.

If $B\simeq B'$, then $E_1\simeq E_2'$ and $E_2\simeq E_1'$, but this cannot happen if $N_1\not\simeq N_2$.

---

Actually, in the case you claim the two operations commute, you've got a problem:
If $N_1\subseteq N_2$, then what is the proper transform of $N_1$ on ${BL}_{N_2}$?